# How to send a pdf file from Node/Express app to the browser

Tags: node.js, express

In my Node/Express app I have the following code, which suppose to read a PDF document from a file, and send it to the browser:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream('./public/modules/datacollectors/output.pdf', 'binary');
var stat = fs.statSync('./public/modules/datacollectors/output.pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=quote.pdf');
res.pipe(file, 'binary');
res.end();
```

I do not get any errors, but I do not get the file in my browser either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: one important detail - I'm trying to send a file back to the browser in response to http POST

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You have to pipe from Readable Stream to Writable stream not the other way around:

```
var file = fs.createReadStream('./public/modules/datacollectors/output.pdf');
var stat = fs.statSync('./public/modules/datacollectors/output.pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=quote.pdf');
file.pipe(res);
```

Also you are setting encoding in wrong way, pass an object with encoding if needed.

Comment: now I can see the file contents being sent to the browser console, but the file still does not 'pop' out of the browser as an attachment.

Comment: found a solution for that?

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg you can use this node module https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver to download the data. You can convert the data to blob as follows var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
 FileSaver.default(blob, fileNameWithExtension);

Comment: `res.send(buffer)` for buffers.

Answer (score 49):

I think I found your answer in another post [Display PDF file in a browser using node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598274/display-pdf-in-browser-using-express-js).

After testing your code in Chrome, it immediately starts the download of the PDF file. But if you want to display the content of the PDF file you could try below:

```
var data =fs.readFileSync('./public/modules/datacollectors/output.pdf');
res.contentType("application/pdf");
res.send(data);
```

This should directly send PDF content into the browser.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 14):

Here's the easiest way:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.download('./file.pdf'))
```

If this gives you trouble. Check the Express.js version or any middlewares that might be necessary.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Best way to download a PDF on REST API call.

```
var path = require('path');     
var file = path.join(__dirname, 'file.pdf');    
res.download(file, function (err) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Error");
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           console.log("Success");
       }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Swagger/OpenAPI then you can look in responses section of below code.

```
/api/pdf_from_html:
  post:
    tags:
      - PDF
    description: Create PDF from html
    produces:
      - application/pdf
    consumes:
      - application/json
    parameters:
      - name: contents
        description: HTML content to convert to pdf
        in:  body
        required: true
        schema:
          $ref: "#/definitions/pdf"
    responses:
      200:
        description: Returns a PDF encoded in base64
        content:
          application/pdf:
            schema:
              type: string
              format: base64
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess it is simple if you want to show it in the browser change content disposition header to "inline" instead of "attachment; filename=quote.pdf"
inline show it directly in the browser instead of download it, it worked fine for me