# Read PDF file in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, express, fs

I am unable to read PDF file in node js.

My code looks like this:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/api/resource', function(req, res) {
filePath = req.query.resource;
fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, file) {
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "application/pdf" });
      res.write(file, "binary");
      res.end();
  });
});
```

But i am not able to get the content of the file in the response.

Comment: Tried with `res.sendFile()` method?

Comment: yes, i tried with res.sendFile() also.

Comment: What *are* you seeing in the response?  Is there actually any content in "file"?  We don't have much information to go on here.

Comment: It's impossible to say what is wrong or might be wrong with a PDF file without seeing the actual PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

as other people said the question itself is not very clear. 
If the function you are trying to implement would let user to download or view a PDF from the browser, then the post below may help you to fine the answer. 
[How to send a pdf file from Node/Express app to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105846/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-from-node-express-app-to-the-browser/45132839#45132839)

However, if you are expecting to read the PDF file into some other format like JSON. Then you may want to check out some 3rd party modules that npm has.

Good luck.