# Send pdf via express to js client and download

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pdf

I am trying to send pdf file from my express server using the client when requested like this:

```
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=test.pdf');
  fs.createReadStream('test.pdf').pipe(res);
```

And then on the client side I am trying to download it by taking the resulting string converting it to a url and downloading from there.

```
var blob = new Blob[pdfString], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var url = window.URL;
var downloadUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
```

However the resulting file is two empty pages and I beleive think it might be because the resulting file is url is to large? If anyone could figure out whats wrong here or tell me of a better way to do it that would be awesome.

Comment: are you using ajax to get binary data ?

Comment: this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105846/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-from-node-express-app-to-the-browser

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way I could use the 'request' http client

Comment: @HaroonKhan Thank you, but I already have the server side set up, I am trying to figure out how to download the response as a pdf file on the client side

Comment: I was able to figure it out using XmlHttpRequest:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using XMlHttpRequest:

```
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open('GET', path , true);
      req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
      req.onload = (event) => {
        downloadPdf(req.response); //This is where I convert to blob
      }
      req.send();
```