# NodeJs/Express display pdf file in browser

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, browser, readfile

I am working on NodeJs/Express project and need to show in the browesr pdf file that is stored in

> /public/images

Here is relevant router code:

```
router.post('/show_file', async (req,res)=>{
  try {
     let path = './public/images/1.pdf'
     var data =fs.readFileSync(path);
     res.contentType("application/pdf");
     res.send(data);
   } catch (err) {
     res.status(500)
     console.log(err)
     res.send(err.message)
   }
})
```

I don't get any errors but nothing is happening ie.browser is not opening etc.
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send a pdf file from Node/Express app to the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31105846/how-to-send-a-pdf-file-from-node-express-app-to-the-browser)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first change that I would do is to remove the `async`. It will just mess out the code with unneeded Promises.

Second, I removed the need to catch the exception, verifying the existence of the file with `fs.existsSync(path)`. Try to not to rise exceptions as often as possible. If you know something can rise an exception, test it.

Last, and most important, I created a reading stream of the file and piped the result to the response with `fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)`. This way, the client recieves the file as it is read and your memory is spared. Great for large files.

Reading a file can be memory intensive, so loading it all in memory is a bad practice. You just need a handfull of request to overload your machine.

You can read more on the pipe method [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/advanced/streams/how-to-use-stream-pipe/).

In this example, any GET call to `/router/show_file` will return the pdf.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fs = require('fs')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/show_file', (req, res) => {
    const path = './public/images/1.pdf'
    if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
        res.contentType("application/pdf");
        fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
    } else {
        res.status(500)
        console.log('File not found')
        res.send('File not found')
    }
})

app.use('/router', router) // Here we pass the router to the app with a path

app.listen(9999, () => console.log('Listening to port 9999'))
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your suggestions. I replaced my code with yours. Still nothing happening in the browser. No error either.

Comment: Are you opening the "/show_file" url directly on browser? If so change from "post" to "get". Browsers use get as the method for urls typed on the address bar.

Comment: I  changed it. Still nothing happening. I am sure I am missing a step. I am using ajax call to get to router. Is that a correct approach?

Comment: If your intent is to show the pdf in a new tab i would use a simple link (<a>) with target blank. But without knowing more it is a wild guess. If you could tell me more details it would help

Comment: I want to be able to display pdf file in the browser window when user clicks on the file name. I can send file name to the router via ajax call and then in the router I hope to get the file from a specified location and display in a new window of the browser.

Comment: Try <a href="/show_file" target="_blank"> in your html code. In this case you don't even need an ajax call. Another thing, how the router and your express application interact? Do you pass it to the application?

Comment: My example is using a static file. My i intend to use it dynamically. I use standard nodejs/express set up. I am new to this and hope it set up properly. I don't have any issues with database call etc. At this point I under impression that I cannot pull file on a client side and have to use server side for that.

Comment: I will edit the answer to fully show teh code I tested and know it works with application and everything. Maybe it will help.