# How do I find path to item in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, pdf, express

I'm using node/express and trying to follow the answers I see here: [Display Pdf in browser using express js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598274/display-pdf-in-browser-using-express-js)

but I'm not sure how to find the path to my PDF file. It's located in the main directory of the project folder, within a folder called "file," so I thought the path would just be

```
./file/myPDF.pdf
```

but I just get a "failed to load PDF document" regardless of the path I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__dirname` solves path problems in node.js. It is always the directory in which the currently executing script resides.

*following is complete working code*:

```
- files
     - my_pdf_file.pdf
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var filePath = "/files/my_pdf_file.pdf";

    fs.readFile(__dirname + filePath , function (err,data){
        res.contentType("application/pdf");
        res.send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on 3000');
});
```

*for complete files and running project*:

Clone node-cheat [pdf_browser](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/pdf/pdf_browser), run `node app` followed by `npm install express`.

Happy Helping!

Answer (score 2):

Using a relative path is not a good idea, NodeJS provide [a "global" to build an absolute path](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname):

```
var myPdf = require('path').normalize(__dirname + '/file/myPDF.pdf');
```