# How to download the pdf file after generated in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm building a web application in Node.js 10.x and angular 6.x. I wish to generate a PDF and download it via browser.

- angular 6.x

```
generatePDF(params): any {
    return this.http.post(this.url('generatePDF'), params, this.getRequestOptions())
      .pipe(map((res: any) => {
          return res;
        })
      );
}
```

- Node.js

```
async generatePDF(options = { format:'A4' }) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ejs.renderFile(this.templateName, this.data, (err, res) => {

        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        pdf.create(res, options)
          .toFile(this.fileName,  (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
              return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(res);
          });
     });
   });
 }
```

Comment: Are you using expressjs? This should help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21788474/1906361

Comment: I have tried but still not working.

Comment: you could try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake

Comment: Generating the PDF is working well. I want to download the pdf via Browser.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in Chrome you can do that with native Chrome pdf reader, or you want to do that clicking on some kind of download button inside of your angular app?

Comment: Yes, the download button is in the angular app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem as follows.

Node.js

```
let pdffilename = username + '_' + gameName.replace(/ /g, "_") + '.pdf'; 
pdfReport = new Report(gameName, ejsfilename, pdffilename, refined_score);  
await pdfReport.generatePDF();
res.sendFile(pdfReport.fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

After Creation of PDF path , you can use the following code to download your file

```
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
  res.header('content-type', 'application/pdf');


  res.download(PDF_PATH, PDF_NAME + '.pdf');
```